# mongo db gridfs throws null pointer exception in play framework 2.3.x java

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, gridfs, morphia

I am following this link:     [mongoDBgridfs](https://www.playframework.com/modules/morphia-1.2.7/model#gridfs). I am using exact code .but while executing blob method it gives null pointer exception. At this line

```
    newUser.photo = new Blob(file, type);
```

but the image is present, I am sure that picture path is correct, there is no mistake in path. one more thing which is notice is: when I give a wrong path then it saves a empty object in database. So it's not database connectivity problem also. I am not getting why this is happening. Is their a mistake in documentation or what?

```
    @Document(collection = "newuser")
    public class NewUser extends Model {

   public String firstName;
   public String lastName;
   public Blob photo;
   DB db;


public static String fileExtension(String fileName) {
    int mid= fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    return fileName.substring(mid+1, fileName.length());
}
// photo upload handler
public static  void uploadPhoto( java.io.File file) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(file);
    NewUserRepository newUserRepository=new NewUserRepository();
    NewUser newUser=new NewUser();
   // String desc="etc";
   // GridFsHelper.storeFile(desc,file);
    String type = "image/" + NewUser.fileExtension(file.getName());
    System.out.println("type"+type);
   newUser.photo = new Blob(file, type);

//    newUserRepository.save(newUser);
}

public  GridFS getGridFS() {

    return new GridFS(db);
}

// fetch photo
public static void getPhoto(String userId) {
    NewUserRepository newUserRepository=new NewUserRepository();


}}
```

My controller is

```
    public static Result gridFsDemoIndex() {
 java.io.File file=new java.io.File("/Users/rajeshbansal/pics/demo2.jpg");

    try {

        NewUser.uploadPhoto(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ok("gridfs worked");
}
```

the exception which comes is

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at leodagdag.play2morphia.Blob.set(Blob.java:50) ~[play2-morphia-plugin_2.9.1-0.0.6.jar:0.0.6]
    at leodagdag.play2morphia.Blob.<init>(Blob.java:34) ~[play2-morphia-plugin_2.9.1-0.0.6.jar:0.0.6]
    at controllers.gridfsdemo.NewUser.uploadPhoto(NewUser.java:37) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.Application.gridFsDemoIndex(Application.java:27) ~[na:na]
    at
```

please help me out.

Comment: First: You got something wrong with the users. You create a new user in your controller and try to upload its picture. Inside the upload-function, you create yet another user.
Second: The NullPointerException, does not mean that your file is null. Check if the created user is null!

Comment: @Peanut i have changed method to static and called it directly ,again the error is coming .

Comment: Check if "newUser" is null before setting the picture (inside the uploadPhoto-function)

Comment: @Peanut actually problem is not null value of user..if i give wrong path of a image then it saves it,,if user is null it wont happen,so user is not null,i am sure .

Comment: @Peanut please help me ,i am stuck on this from a long time .

Comment: Can you get the example to work (without modifying it)?

Comment: @Peanut .thanks peanut from your point i tried a normal example and then i realized where i was wrong.now its all working ,thanks so much dear

Comment: You're welcome. Consider to summarize what you learned (or what solution worked) and answer your own question. It might help others.

Comment: @Peanut ok i update this

Answer (score 0):

there was problem in database connectivity.i was merging mongo with morphia module but not giving databse settings to morphia.then i decided to do only with mongo db and followed this link

http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/07/23/java-mongodb-getsave-image-using-gridfs-apis/.its done